# how pass TextField text from QString in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

**Hi Guys, i need take the text of TextField QML then pass to QString in C++.**

Firstpage.qml:

```
Component {

    id: mainView

    Row {

        Image {
            id: logo
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: "Imagens/jscalcadosLogo.png"
        }

        ColumnLayout {
            id: layoutLogin
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            anchors.margins: 3
            spacing: 3

            TextField {
                id: login
                objectName: "login"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                placeholderText: "Username"

            }
```

Main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("FirstPage.qml"));
QObject *object = view->rootObject();
QObject    *textin = object->findChild<QObject*>("login");
//QString input = textin->Property("text").toString(); // crash the program

return app.exec();
}
```

When i try convert Textin to QString the program crash

any idea ? i'm sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general rule is: *Don't read or write something in QML from C++*

Instead, you shall create a `QObject`-derived instance in C++ that has a property for that text. You expose that `QObject` to QML, either by setting it as a context property or registering it as a singleton.

Then in QML you set afore-mentioned property - et voila - you have pushed the text from the QML world to the C++.

There are various questions on StackOverflow regarding the interaction of C++ and QML (I might search for them later, and probably flag your question as duplicate, for I am sure your question is not the first).

Also the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-overview.html) has more information on this.

Comment: "The general rule is: Don't read or write something in QML from C++" but i need use this connection because i try use Mysql in c++ to connect with my QML app and the "documentation" is not clear. i need pass this QObject to QString, any idea ?

Comment: @CésarAugusto Create a class that inherits from QObject where your methods are in charge of doing the procedure you require, in your case interact with the database, and expose it to QML using a context property or singleton, then use that task on the QML side that execute the code implemented on the C ++ side.